# Problem with $.each() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, json

I want append some from array by `jQuery.each` and data `hotel_id`, number each `hotel_id` is 4, and this loop `$.each(data[0].hotel_id,... });` run 4 times contents inside self, in case that there are or inserted in database rows `residence_u` and `residence_p` 3 times (each of they there are 3, not 4(like `hotel_id`)), when run the following code, this code not have error jus not work. if i remove codes `$.each(info_ru.units,... });` and `$.each(info_rp.start_date,... });` it worked: How can fix it?

See full my js code: [**http://pastebin.com/jBWEDZrN**][1]

This is summary from my js code in ajax call(`url: 'get_gr',`):

```
$.each(data[0].hotel_id, function (index, value) {
    var $li = $('<li><input name="hotel_id[]" value="' + value.hotel_id + '" style="display:none;"></li>');
    var $tooltip = $('<div class="tooltip"></div>').appendTo($li);
    $li.appendTo('#residence_name');

    var info_ru = data[0].residence_u[index];
    $.each(info_ru.units, function (index, value) {
        $tooltip.append(value + ' & ' + info_ru.extra[index] + ' & ' + info_ru.price[index] + '<br>');
    });

    var info_rp = data[0].residence_p[index];
    $.each(info_rp.start_date, function (index, value) {
        $tooltip.append(value + ' & ' + info_rp.end_date[index] + ' & ' + info_rp.price_change[index] + '<br>');
    });
    tool_tip()
});
```

This is output php code(`url: 'get_gr',`):

```
[{
    "guide": null,
    "hotel_id": [{
        "hotel_id": ["1"]
    }, {
        "hotel_id": ["2"]
    }, {
        "hotel_id": ["3"]
    }, {
        "hotel_id": ["4"]
    }],
    "residence_u": [{
        "units": ["hello", "how", "what"],
        "extra": ["11", "22", "33"],
        "price": ["1,111,111", "2,222,222", "3,333,333"]
    }, {
        "units": ["fine"],
        "extra": ["44"],
        "price": ["4,444,444"]
    }, {
        "units": ["thanks", "good"],
        "extra": ["55", "66"],
        "price": ["5,555,555", "6,666,666"]
    }],
    "residence_p": [{
        "start_date": ["1111", "2222"],
        "end_date": ["1111", "2222"],
        "price_change": ["1111", "2222"]
    }, {
        "start_date": ["3333", "4444"],
        "end_date": ["3333", "4444"],
        "price_change": ["3333", "4444"]
    }, {
        "start_date": ["5555", "6666"],
        "end_date": ["5555", "6666"],
        "price_change": ["5555", "6666"]
    }]
}]
```

**Update:**

I insert several(`array`) value with `json_encode` in one row from database table, now want echo they as order with jquery.

Output js code is this:

> `1`
>  `hello` & `11` & `1,111,111`
>  `how` & `22` & `2,222,222`
>  `what` & `33`
>   & `3,333,333,`
>  `1111` & `1111` & `1111` 
>  `2222` & `2222` & `2222`

> `2`
>  `fine` & `44` & `4,444,444`
>  `3333` & `3333` & `3333` 
>  `4444` & `4444` & `4444`

> `3`
>  `thanks` & `55` & `5,555,555`
>  `good` & `66` & `6,666,666`
>  `5555` & `5555` & `5555` 
>  `6666` & `6666` & `6666`

> `4`

Comment: It is quite hard to tell what you are trying to do with so much test rather than meaningful data. I have tried to pull together your components to see if it makes any more sense when running http://jsfiddle.net/TStKJ/ but it seems to run without errors as far as I can tell.  Could the error be in your ToolTip() method?

Comment: @AliciaCibrian: Continuing the conversation from the other question, if the quantity of `hotel_id` and `residence_u` and `residence_p` should be equal, then I don't know what you should do when they're not. Should each `hotel_id` object have its own `residence_u` and `residence_p` objects? If so why don't they and why aren't they grouped together in the JSON structure?

Answer (score 0):

You only have 3 elements in your residence_u and 2 in residence_p arrays, but 4 in the original hotels array.  Could it be as simple as to check for a valid info_ru

```
var info_ru = data[0].residence_u[index];
if ( infor_ru != null ) {
    $.each(info_ru.units, function (index, value) {
        $tooltip.append(value + ' & ' + info_ru.extra[index] + ' & ' + info_ru.price[index] + '<br>');
    });
}
```

before continuing with the each?

Comment: That right. how can run it in code? please give me example in the code.

Comment: No, that's not right. `data[0].hotel_id` doesn't contain a dictionary, it contains an array of dictionaries. The value of `index` will be the numerical index in the array.