# Initialise a counter before the first loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, each, json

This line

```
$.each(data[0].hotel_id, function (index, value) {
```

Loops through `hotel_id` array executing the inner JS code for each entry in the dictionary setting index to the key in the dictionary and value to the contents.

My dictionary:

```
"hotel_id": [{
    "hotel_id": ["1"]
}, {
    "hotel_id": ["2"]
}, {
    "hotel_id": ["3"]
}, {
    "hotel_id": ["4"]
}],
```

Has all items with the same index, therefore the value of index will always be 'hotel_id', which is no use to i when i try to use it to find the relevant extra data from my other dictionaries.

I would initialise a counter before the first loop and increment it on each iteration then use this value to find the associated extra data from the other arrays.

See full my js code: [**http://pastebin.com/jBWEDZrN**](http://pastebin.com/jBWEDZrN)

This is summary from my js code in ajax call(`url: 'get_gr',`):

```
$.each(data[0].hotel_id, function (index, value) {
    var $li = $('<li><input name="hotel_id[]" value="' + value.hotel_id + '" style="display:none;"></li>');
    var $tooltip = $('<div class="tooltip"></div>').appendTo($li);
    $li.appendTo('#residence_name');

    var info_ru = data[0].residence_u[index];
    $.each(info_ru.units, function (index, value) {
        $tooltip.append(value + ' & ' + info_ru.extra[index] + ' & ' + info_ru.price[index] + '<br>');
    });

    var info_rp = data[0].residence_p[index];
    $.each(info_rp.start_date, function (index, value) {
        $tooltip.append(value + ' & ' + info_rp.end_date[index] + ' & ' + info_rp.price_change[index] + '<br>');
    });
    tool_tip()
});
```

This is output php code(`url: 'get_gr',`):

```
[{
    "guide": null,
    "hotel_id": [{
        "hotel_id": ["1"]
    }, {
        "hotel_id": ["2"]
    }, {
        "hotel_id": ["3"]
    }, {
        "hotel_id": ["4"]
    }],
    "residence_u": [{
        "units": ["hello", "how", "what"],
        "extra": ["11", "22", "33"],
        "price": ["1,111,111", "2,222,222", "3,333,333"]
    }, {
        "units": ["fine"],
        "extra": ["44"],
        "price": ["4,444,444"]
    }, {
        "units": ["thanks", "good"],
        "extra": ["55", "66"],
        "price": ["5,555,555", "6,666,666"]
    }],
    "residence_p": [{
        "start_date": ["1111", "2222"],
        "end_date": ["1111", "2222"],
        "price_change": ["1111", "2222"]
    }, {
        "start_date": ["3333", "444"],
        "end_date": ["3333", "4444"],
        "price_change": ["3333", "4444"]
    }, {
        "start_date": ["5555", "6666"],
        "end_date": ["5555", "6666"],
        "price_change": ["5555", "6666"]
    }]
}]
```

What do i do?

**Update:**(this update is for above output php)

I insert several(`array`) value with `json_encode` in one row from database table, now want echo they as order with jquery.

Output js code is this:

> `1`
>  `hello` & `11` & `1,111,111`
>  `how` & `22` & `2,222,222`
>  `what` & `33`
>   & `3,333,333,`
>  `1111` & `1111` & `1111` 
>  `2222` & `2222` & `2222`

> `2`
>  `fine` & `44` & `4,444,444`
>  `3333` & `3333` & `3333` 
>  `4444` & `4444` & `4444`

> `3`
>  `thanks` & `55` & `5,555,555`
>  `good` & `66` & `6,666,666`
>  `5555` & `5555` & `5555` 
>  `6666` & `6666` & `6666`

> `4`

Comment: Nice **loooong** question and all, **but** where is the real question??

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581167/problem-with-each-in-jquery/7581671#7581671 . now waht do i do?

Comment: If you don't understand the answer to a question, do not create a new question asking for an explanation of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

No, your array doesn't have items with the same index. It has items with different indexes, but the value is an object that contains a property with the same name for each object. The index will go from `0` to `3` if the array has four items as in the example.

You can use `value.hotel_id` in the loop to get the array that is the value of the property, for example `["1"]`.

If the array in the property only ever contains one id, you can just use `value.hotel_id[0]` to get that id.

Example:

```
$.each(data[0].hotel_id, function (index, value) {
  alert(value.hotel_id[0]);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/BWLqw/

Comment: I think she is referring to looping over hotel_id array of hotel_id objects. I admit it is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581167/problem-with-each-in-jquery/7581671#7581671 . now waht do i do?

Comment: I not have problem that you explain.

Comment: @Alicia Cibrian: The answer to that question is not correct. `data[0].hotel_id` doesn't contain a dictionary (object), it contains an array of dictionaries. You will be looping the items (dictionaries) in the array, not the properties in the dictionaries in the array. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/BWLqw/

Comment: I think the issue @AliciaCibrian must be having is that there are four `data[0].hotel_id` items but only three `data[0].residence_u` items. So when the outer loop gets to `index === 3`, there isn't a `data[0].residence_u[index]`. I just don't know what the expectation is.

Comment: `Ӫ_._Ӫ` - that's right. `Guffa` your answer not for my problem. I think that `Ӫ_._Ӫ` understand my problem

Comment: @AliciaCibrian: Well I may understand the code issue, but I don't understand the final result that you want. Do you really want each index of `data[0].hotel_id` to correspond with an index of `data[0].residence_u`? Or for every `data[0].hotel_id` do you actually want to loop over *all* the `data[0].residence_u` items. I just can't tell what you're trying to achieve. *(And @Guffa's answer correctly addressed the problem you stated, which was based on the incorrect answer to the other question. This is why it is better to stick with one question until it is resolved.)*

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - please see my update post, in first post. Do you understand my purpose?

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ  - If in database a row or data(`hotel_id` Or `residence_u` Or `residence_p`) delete or insert, this code not work.

Comment: @AliciaCibrian: I'll address your comments in your other question. Please click the large checkmark to the left of this answer since it did answer your original question.

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - I can not find the answer you, where is it?

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - where is it? Please tell me

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ - I don't understand your purpose in last your comment. !!!? did you say that i accept this answer and make new Question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the point of using `each` and an anonymous function.

I would just use a for loop.

```
for(var n = 0; n < data[0].hotel_id.length; n++) {
  // put your function code here or call a named func(data[0].hotel_id[n])
}
```

I only use each if I am applying a function that I would reuse elsewhere.

Comment: Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7581167/problem-with-each-in-jquery/7581671#7581671 . now waht do i do?